# Cannot write to /etc/fstab in maintenance mode

Tags: startup, readonly, system-recovery

I am using Oracle Linux 6.5. Due to bad entries in `/etc/fstab`, `fstab` errors occurred on startup and I am unable to log in.

It's asking me for the root password to enter maintenance mode. When I enter it to fix `fstab`, it does not allow me to write or make any changes.

Answer (score 3):

The root filesysetm is mounted in read-only mode in conditions like this.  Remount as:

```
mount -t FSTYPE -oremount,rw DEVICE /
```

...where FSTYPE is the filesystem type (likely 'ext4').

This will leave the filesystem in a read-write mode.